# Spring Mail fails second time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, spring-bean

I implemented spring email using MimeMessageHelper

```
@Bean
public MimeMessage  getMimeMessage(){
    MimeMessage message = emailSender.createMimeMessage();
    return message;
}

@Bean
public MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper(){
    MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);      
    helper.setTo(to);
    helper.setSubject(subject);
    helper.setText(text);
}
```

All the beans are Autowired. When I call JavaMailSender.send(MimeMessage) for the first time the email is sent. but when I call the send method for the second time, the email is not sent. Please provide suggestions

Comment: Don't use the `MimeMessage` and `MimeMessageHelper` like that. For each mail that needs to be send create a new `MimeMessage` and `MimeMessageHelper`. Those aren't thread safe.

Comment: Probably inject scopes. Try to add @RequestScope to mimeMessageHelper()

Comment: @Bejond don't. The `MimeMessage` and `MimeMessageHelper` aren't designed for that. Instead just use them in the way they are supposed to be used. The fact that one uses Spring doesn't mean that everything has to be controlled by Spring.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes. creating new instances worked. Could you please elaborate on why the same instance won't work ?